# Is there a quick fix for a syntax error in my JOIN operation

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm fairly new to sql and am probably over my head with this but I keep running into a syntax error in my join statement.

I am trying to get specific stats for a single character. I have added more parenthese to get rid of a missing operator error, and I have tried adding parenthese to only around the inner joins of the same tables. So far the join statement is the only thing throwing errors.

```
SELECT CHARACTER.CharacterName, CHARACTER.Alignment, INVENTORY.Equipped, 
ITEMS.ItemName,
ITEMS.PhysDef, ITEMS.MDef, ITEMS.Dodge, ITEMS.Damage, ITEMS.CritMultiplier, 
ITEMS.Range,
ITEMS.AttackSpeed, JOB_CHARACTER.JobLevel, RACE_CHARACTER.RacialLevel, 
RACE.RaceName, RACE.Strength,
RACE.Skill, RACE.Vitality, RACE.Arcane, RACE.Spirit, RACE.Charisma, 
RACE.Luck, JOB.JobName,
JOB.HP, JOB.AttackBonus, JOB.Agility, JOB.Might, JOB.SpellPower, JOB.Vital, 
JOB.Nimble, JOB.Mental,
JOB.Curese, JOB.SpellCasting, JOB.ManaBase, JOB.ManaType, JOB.Ki, 
SKILLS.Alchemy, SKILLS.Awareness,
SKILLS.Climb, SKILLS.Coach, SKILLS.Construction, SKILLS.Decieve, 
SKILLS.DisarmMechanism,
SKILLS.DiscernTruth, SKILLS.Dishearten, SKILLS.Fly, SKILLS.Forge, 
SKILLS.Gymnastics,SKILLS.Identify,
SKILLS.Leadership, SKILLS.Lore_9Realms, SKILLS.Lore_Alternative, 
SKILLS.Lore_Arcane,
SKILLS.Lore_Arithmancy, SKILLS.Lore_Divine, SKILLS.Lore_Geography, 
SKILLS.Lore_Nature,
SKILLS.Lore_Nobility, SKILLS.Lore_Religion, SKILLS.Lore_Spiritual, 
SKILLS.Medical, 
SKILLS.Performance, SKILLS.Ride, SKILLS.Steal, SKILLS.Stealth, 
SKILLS.Subterfuge,
SKILLS.Swim, SKILLS.Tailor, SKILLS.UseContraption, SKILLS.Wilderness

FROM (((((((CHARACTER INNER JOIN RACE_CHARACTER ON 
CHARACTER.CharacterID=RACE_CHARACTER.CharacterID)
LEFT JOIN JOB_CHARACTER ON CHARACTER.CharacterID=JOB_CHARACTER.CharacterID)
LEFT JOIN INVENTORY ON CHARACTER.CharacterID=INVENTORY.CharacterID)
INNER JOIN INVENTORY ON ITEMS.ItemID =INVENTORY.ItemID)
INNER JOIN JOB ON JOB.JobID=JOB_CHARACTER.JobID)
LEFT JOIN SKILLS ON JOB.JobID=SKILLS.JobID)
INNER JOIN RACE ON RACE.RaceID=RACE_CHARACTER.RaceID)

WHERE  ((CHARACTER.CharacterID)=1) AND ((JOB.JobID)=3) AND 
((RACE.RaceID)=6);
```

I expect this to output the stats for this single character, its name, and skills, however it is not currently outputting anything.

Comment: Did you use Access query builder to construct this SQL? Access will do the parenthesizing for you. Try adding one table at a time and viewing the data until it fails to show what you expect.

Comment: @BenJ . . . The most likely reason this returns no rows is because nothing matches the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Can you post the error details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `select` statement is sourcing 8 fields from an `ITEMS` table:

```
SELECT 
    ...
    ITEMS.ItemName,
    ITEMS.PhysDef, 
    ITEMS.MDef,
    ITEMS.Dodge,
    ITEMS.Damage, 
    ITEMS.CritMultiplier, 
    ITEMS.Range,
    ITEMS.AttackSpeed,
    ...
```

However, the `ITEMS` table is **not** referenced by your `from` clause:

```
FROM 
    (
        (
            (
                (
                    (
                        (
                            (
                                CHARACTER INNER JOIN RACE_CHARACTER ON 
                                CHARACTER.CharacterID=RACE_CHARACTER.CharacterID
                            )
                            LEFT JOIN JOB_CHARACTER ON 
                            CHARACTER.CharacterID=JOB_CHARACTER.CharacterID
                        )
                        LEFT JOIN INVENTORY ON 
                        CHARACTER.CharacterID=INVENTORY.CharacterID
                    )
                    INNER JOIN INVENTORY ON ----------< INVENTORY table referenced twice
                    ITEMS.ItemID =INVENTORY.ItemID
                )
                INNER JOIN JOB ON 
                JOB.JobID=JOB_CHARACTER.JobID
            )
            LEFT JOIN SKILLS ON 
            JOB.JobID=SKILLS.JobID
        )
        INNER JOIN RACE ON 
        RACE.RaceID=RACE_CHARACTER.RaceID
    )
```

I should imagine the SQL code should be changed to something like:

```
SELECT 
    CHARACTER.CharacterName, 
    CHARACTER.Alignment, 
    INVENTORY.Equipped, 
    ITEMS.ItemName,
    ITEMS.PhysDef, 
    ITEMS.MDef,
    ITEMS.Dodge,
    ITEMS.Damage, 
    ITEMS.CritMultiplier, 
    ITEMS.Range,
    ITEMS.AttackSpeed, 
    JOB_CHARACTER.JobLevel,
    RACE_CHARACTER.RacialLevel, 
    RACE.RaceName, 
    RACE.Strength,
    RACE.Skill,
    RACE.Vitality, 
    RACE.Arcane, 
    RACE.Spirit, 
    RACE.Charisma, 
    RACE.Luck,
    JOB.JobName,
    JOB.HP, 
    JOB.AttackBonus, 
    JOB.Agility, 
    JOB.Might, 
    JOB.SpellPower,
    JOB.Vital, 
    JOB.Nimble, 
    JOB.Mental,
    JOB.Curese, 
    JOB.SpellCasting,
    JOB.ManaBase, 
    JOB.ManaType, 
    JOB.Ki, 
    SKILLS.Alchemy, 
    SKILLS.Awareness,
    SKILLS.Climb, 
    SKILLS.Coach, 
    SKILLS.Construction, 
    SKILLS.Decieve, 
    SKILLS.DisarmMechanism,
    SKILLS.DiscernTruth, 
    SKILLS.Dishearten, 
    SKILLS.Fly, 
    SKILLS.Forge, 
    SKILLS.Gymnastics,
    SKILLS.Identify,
    SKILLS.Leadership, 
    SKILLS.Lore_9Realms, 
    SKILLS.Lore_Alternative, 
    SKILLS.Lore_Arcane,
    SKILLS.Lore_Arithmancy, 
    SKILLS.Lore_Divine, 
    SKILLS.Lore_Geography, 
    SKILLS.Lore_Nature,
    SKILLS.Lore_Nobility, 
    SKILLS.Lore_Religion, 
    SKILLS.Lore_Spiritual, 
    SKILLS.Medical, 
    SKILLS.Performance, 
    SKILLS.Ride, 
    SKILLS.Steal, 
    SKILLS.Stealth, 
    SKILLS.Subterfuge,
    SKILLS.Swim, 
    SKILLS.Tailor, 
    SKILLS.UseContraption, 
    SKILLS.Wilderness
FROM 
    (
        (
            (
                (
                    (
                        (
                            (
                                CHARACTER INNER JOIN RACE_CHARACTER ON 
                                CHARACTER.CharacterID=RACE_CHARACTER.CharacterID
                            )
                            LEFT JOIN JOB_CHARACTER ON 
                            CHARACTER.CharacterID=JOB_CHARACTER.CharacterID
                        )
                        LEFT JOIN INVENTORY ON 
                        CHARACTER.CharacterID=INVENTORY.CharacterID
                    )
                    LEFT JOIN ITEMS ON 
                    ITEMS.ItemID =INVENTORY.ItemID
                )
                LEFT JOIN JOB ON 
                JOB.JobID=JOB_CHARACTER.JobID
            )
            LEFT JOIN SKILLS ON 
            JOB.JobID=SKILLS.JobID
        )
        INNER JOIN RACE ON 
        RACE.RaceID=RACE_CHARACTER.RaceID
    )
WHERE 
    CHARACTER.CharacterID = 1 AND
    JOB.JobID = 3 AND 
    RACE.RaceID = 6
```

Note that I have changed a couple of the `inner joins` to `left joins` because if you use an `inner join` on a table which is the right of a `left join` (or on the left of a `right join`), then you will receive an *ambiguous outer joins* error.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you so much! And thank you for the heads  up about the _ambiguous outer joins error,_ that helped me fix an error on another database project!